# User input 10 times into an arraylist

Tags: arraylist

I am fairly new to Java but I cannot find the answer to this question.
Is it possible to add user input a set amount of times of integers and store them into an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes. You ask ten times and on each time call `list.add(value);`

Comment: To repeat an action you use a `for` loop.

Comment: public static void main (String [] args) {       
        // create an arraylist and read in 10 values
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //create a array list of Integers
        ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        // ask user to enter 10 integers
        System.out.print("Enter ten integers: ");
        int value;
        
        while (input.hasNextInt()){
            value = listOfNumbers.add(input.nextInteger());
        }

        System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
        
    }      
}

Comment: OP  add that code in your original answer to be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you're looking for, but you can try something like this :

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.println("Input number " + i);
    arr.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.